# MongoDB mongos memory usage

Tags: memory, mongodb

Planning how to deploy a shard-ready cluster (Single shard at the moment, with all config servers and mongos processes), I've read the [MongoDB operations best practices](http://info.mongodb.com/rs/mongodb/images/10gen-MongoDB_Operations_Best_Practices.pdf).
I have doubts about the memory usage they state there.

They claim that each mongos will require:
* Size of shard config metadata.
* 1 MB for each connection (client connections + connections to each instance in the shard)

What worries me is aggregations that (as far as I understand) happen on the mongos processes.
Seems to me that it's a bit hard to assess how much memory this will take.

What am I missing? Do aggregations happen somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: We need more details . Like number of collections , objet your put in the database etc . There is not a all in one math solution for that . You have to test with a small dataset .

Comment: You mean that there's more to it regarding mongos memory usage than what's written in that doc?